# axios response converted into Proxy Object after assigning it to data property in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am assigning axios response to data property . But it is changing it to proxy Object.

Axios response

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: 8, internal_control_number: "1234567", date_of_work: "02/24/2021", agent: "6", ranch: "2", …}
1: {id: 3, internal_control_number: "12345678765432", date_of_work: "2021-02-24", agent: "6", ranch: "1", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

after assigning it to data property

```
[[Handler]]: Object
deleteProperty: ƒ deleteProperty(target, key)
get: ƒ (target, key, receiver)
has: ƒ has(target, key)
ownKeys: ƒ ownKeys(target)
set: ƒ (target, key, value, receiver)
__proto__: Object
[[Target]]: Array(2)
0: {id: 8, internal_control_number: "1234567", date_of_work: "02/24/2021", agent: "6", ranch: "2", …}
1: {id: 3, internal_control_number: "12345678765432", date_of_work: "2021-02-24", agent: "6", ranch: "1", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

My axios request, When I assign response.data to this.workOrders it changes into proxyObject

```
export default defineComponent({
  components: { 
    IonItem, 
    IonList, 
    IonLabel,
    SideMenu,
    
  },
  data(){
    return {
    work_orders : {},
    }  
  },
  methods:{
   getWorkOrders :function()
   { 
  
     const boss_id =   TokenService.getUserInfo().role_details.id;

    return  ApiService.get(`/api/gangBoss/workOrders/view/${boss_id}`).then((response) =>{
   
     this.work_orders =  response.data;
       console.log(this.work_orders)
       console.log(response.data)
    });
   }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.getWorkOrders();
  }
```

Comment: Try changing `work_orders : {}` to `work_orders: null`

Comment: then i am getting error in v-for ```
<ion-item :v-for="(work_order,index) in this.work_orders" :key="index">
      <ion-label >{{work_order}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>``` here is error ``` WorkOrder.vue?7a20:20 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'undefined' in null```

Comment: So just define it as empty something like `work_orders: ''`.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? I am facing the same issue ^^